# Is there any way to present an overall value based on items in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part

To clarify the question, we're aiming to use SharePoint lists to manage risks on a project. We've built a Risk Log in Excel which includes an overall risk based on the level of risks within the table (i.e. 20% of risks being high would lead to a high overall risk, all risks being low would lead to a low overall risk, etc.).

In Excel, we're able to have a cell at the top of the workbook that simply calculates the overall risk based on the contents of the 'Risk Level' column. Is there any way to duplicate this behaviour on a page with a SharePoint list?

I tried to export the list to Excel and save that to Site Assets, create another table within the workbook with the overall calculation, and display that through an Excel Web Access Web Part, but I needed to open the workbook in order to refresh and update the calculation. I'm hoping there's some way to have this calculation automatically update as the list is updated, if possible.

I'm wondering if there might be some way to do it in the Script Editor Web Part, but I have little to no experience working with script beyond some simple copy-and-paste jobs.

Any ideas would be appreciated, and please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using totals under Modify View or Create view. You can do the average of Risk Level. Not sure if this meets what you are asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only work on number fields. Ours is a calculated column that will display 'High', 'Medium', or 'Low' depending on a number of other fields.

Comment: You could add a calculated field that sets a number value when selecting High, Medium or Low. Than do the math calculation on this newly added column, this will let you see the risk level.